# Once off-canvas menu is closed, fixed div's no longer fixed

Tags: jquery, html, menu, fixed

I am using an off-canvas menu that works great. I also have div's that are fixed which also work great. These are: top header, a mini-icon nav and a back to top button.

Once I open the off-canvas menu, then close it, and return to the same page, the 3 div's that were fixed are no longer fixed...they scroll with the rest of the page. Refreshing the page makes them stick again, but once I open that menu and close it...the problem repeats itself.

Any thoughts out there to where I can start digging in the code?

Comment: Could you add the relevant source code to your post?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I have this issue. The menu stays at its fixed position, not matter how often I open and close it. Are you having this issue in all browsers? BTW, even though it’s cumbersome, I’d recommend you extract the relevant parts and add them here. Folks on Stack Overflow are more likely to help then.

Comment: The issue isn't the menu staying fixed. It works fine. The issue is when you resize your browser to emulate a mobile device and the off-canvas menu appears. There are 3 other elements that are fixed: 1) a side icon navigation on the right, 2) a 'back to top' button at the bottom right, and 3) the div that is holding the off-canvas menu trigger (hamburger icon). When I first visit the page, everything works great and stays fixed. Once I open the off-canvas menu and then close it...those 3 elements I mentioned above, are no longer fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the plugin. It was using 100% heights which turned out to be a huge problem causer with a lot of things. Going with a better plugin. Not sure how close this issue, so posting an answer will do it?